# Touch pad not working Yoga 2 Pro Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, yoga-2

I could really use some help with troubleshooting my touch pad. I believe it is a hardware issue but I would like to be sure. Lenovo will not help me unless I have the original OS on the laptop... why would anyone leave Windows 8 on their pc on purpose?? Any way... I've looked at a few other posts, here is the output from the following command:

```
yogapro@yogapro:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Also of note, when I run Ubuntu from a thumbdrive I am still unable to use the touchpad. Any suggestions? I appreciate the help!

Comment: I would like to suggest you to paste `dmesg` message to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ it will provide some clues for the touchpad.

Comment: Thank you I will upload the results as soon as I get back home!

Comment: dmesg link below :)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9535418/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the Logitech USB Receiver is your wireless mouse?
I can't see any sign of your touchpad from the dmesg output, which should look like this if it works:

```
[ 10.706] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event4)
[ 10.706] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[ 10.706] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[ 10.706] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[ 10.706] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[ 10.706] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
```

Which means that the touchpad wan't detected by the kernel at all, this might be a bug or even a hardware failure.

I would suggest you to give 14.04 a try (live desktop is fine), since it seems that the touchpad on Yoga 2 Pro works fine with 3.13 kernel from this bug report on launchpad:
 [On Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad detected as pointer device by Xorg](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372520).

If it's a bug in 3.16 kernel, please report it with `ubuntu-bug linux` command in your terminal, and you can follow the detailed debugging instruction from [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).

Good luck!

Comment: I ran 14.04 live and still no sign of the touchpad. Not super surprised but a little bummed. Honestly the quality of this yoga 2 pro leaves a lot to be desired. Now I have to install windows back on here or Lenovo won't try to repair it. Thank you for your help!!!